# Cálculo do frete não retorna erros

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo que faz o cálculo do frete. O cálculo funciona perfeitamente, o problema está caso eu digite o CEP 11111111, ele não informa que o cep é inválido.

```
$correios = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?nCdEmpresa=&sDsSenha=&sCepOrigem=XXXXXXXX&sCepDestino=".$_POST["cepDestino"]."&nVlPeso=".$somaPeso."&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=".$jmProdutos->Comprimento."&nVlAltura=".$somaAltura."&nVlLargura=".$jmProdutos->Largura."&sCdMaoPropria=s&nVlValorDeclarado=0&sCdAvisoRecebimento=s&nCdServico=04014,04510&nVlDiametro=0&StrRetorno=xml";
$correiosInfo = simplexml_load_file($correios);

foreach($correiosInfo->cServico as $linhas) {

 if($linhas->Erro == 0) {

    // Ok.. aqui vou listar os valores
   }else{
     echo $linhas->MsgErro;
  }

}
```

Comment: E como você está validando o CEP?

Comment: Provavelmente se não está validando 11111111, não estará validando 22222222, até 99999999

Comment: Pensei que na $linhas->MsgErro; já trouxesse o erro.

Comment: Isso é óbvio Everton :/

Comment: Ele valida qualquer número de 7 ou 8 dígitos :/...

Comment: Ok.. já entendi o problema. Vou validar o CEP antes. Como disse antes, pensei que a  $linhas->MsgErro; já trouxesse essa validação. Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem tiver passando pelo mesmo problema, pode validar da seguinte forma:

```
var cepDestino    = document.getElementById("cepDestino").value;

$.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cepDestino +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

if (!("erro" in dados)){

  // Aqui entra seu código

}else{
     alert("CEP não encontrado.");
 }
});
```